# Inverting Polygons using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, geometry

I have a Shapefile with Polygon features  representing the world's land areas (continents, islands).

Is it possible to invert these, and get a geometry that represents the world's oceans and seas?

So the original land Polygons need to become rings in a single global Polygon that covers the planet.

Basically, I'm looking for something like Select > Inverse in Photoshop.

I am using QGIS.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do this using the following steps:

1- In QGIS go to `Vector > Research Tools > Polygon From Layer Extent`. Use the World's Land area as Input File. Choose the Desired name for the output file name of extent layer. This will create a new vector layer covering the Whole Land area.

2- Use `Geoprocessing Tools > Difference`: Use the extent layer created in step one as input file and world's land area as difference file. Then You will get an opposite shapefile which represents the ocean.

Comment: I'm accepting this, because generally this seems to be the right technique. Matte is right though: some of the ocean will be missing.

Answer (score 8):

When you invert the polygons its probably missing a small amount of ocean in the end as the extend of the landmass will not go up to the northpole and therefore the difference may lack a bit there. Depending on what should be done with the data afterwards it might be better to just get the ocean data.

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/features/

Comment: I considered Natural Earth, but I need more detailed coastlines.

Comment: This is interesting because there is no point at which a coastline is 'detailed' enough; there will always be more detail available in the natural world. For the US east coast, I know the coastline available from NOAA ( https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/shorelines/ ) wasn't enough for me.

Comment: I ended up going with an excellent OSM-based dataset. It's detailed enough for me. http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/water-polygons

Answer (score 3):

Additional to ahmadhanb answer, you can create a buffer of a few degrees/km/miles to the "Polygon from Layer Extent", in this fashion you will have some space out of the most external vertices of your continental shapes (which is what you obtain).

Then, you may apply "Difference" to this buffered shape to erase you continent polygons and obtain the ocean.